# Как достать файл /data/data/com.vitvov.profit/databases/profitDB из защищенной директории Android без ROOT-прав, экрана и включенной отладки по USB?

Tags: android, экран, root

В данном файле хранятся важные данные, которые не хотелось бы потерять.
Экран телефона был разбит настолько, что управлять телефоном стало невозможно.
Сейчас экран лежит отдельно от телефона.
Прошивка стоковая. Телефон никогда не рутовался. Рекавери родное (я его даже никогда не запускал).
Отладка по USB на момент перед разбитием экрана была выключена, соответственно рутануть вряд ли получится.

Comment: Самый простой способ проверить- запустите установку MyPhoneExplorer. Если установится- значит Вы в шоколаде! Если затребует включить отладку- похода в СЦ на замену дисплея не избежать... OTG робит?

Comment: Пробовал. MyPhoneExplorer не видит его. Когда-то пробовал подключить флешку к этому телефону через OTG, но безуспешно. Поэтому, скорее всего, мышь не получится подключить.

Comment: Минуточку, Вы можете зайти в стоковое рекавери? И еще напишите модель устройства, если есть возможность - давайте свяжемся в соц, Сетях

Comment: Зайти в стоковое рекавери никогда не пробовал, когда на устройстве был экран. Вот модель телефона http://www.lg.com/ru/smartphones/lg-D295-smartphones  Давайте свяжемся: https://vk.com/aagah6aaeaacuchaam Или киньте ссылку на себя.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Купил б/у телефон такой же модели.
Из старого телефона сделал через LG PC Suite резервную копию данных.
На новый телефон через LG PC Suite закачал этот бэкап и получил клон старого телефона только с целым экраном. Далее рутанул новый телефон и достал необходимый файл.
Спасибо за помощь. Комментарии хоть прямо и не не помогли, но натолкнули на правильные мысли.